# bootstrap navigation tabs not showing properly when active

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The bootstrap navigation bar below is malfunctioning.  The 'home', 'message', and 'public1' tabs change to the desired deep blue background when clicked.

Specifically, the public2, public3, public4, and register tabs only give a shadow background when clicked.  The problem with `public2`, public3`, and`public4`is that clicking on them causes`public1`to turn deep blue, while the selected tab gets a shadow background.  Similarly, when`register`is clicked, the`register` button is shadowed, but everything else has a white background.

The desired effect is for the chosen/active tab to be deep blue.  **What specific changes need to be made to the code below to get any selected tab to be deep blue?**

```
    <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
        <li ng-class="{active:tab('home')}"><a href="/">home</a></li>
        <li ng-class="{active:tab('message')}"><a href="/message">message</a></li>
        <li ng-class="{active:tab('public1')}"><a href="/public1">public1</a></li>
        <li ng-class="{active:tab('public2')}"><a href="/public2">public2</a></li>
        <li ng-class="{active:tab('public3')}"><a href="/public3">public3</a></li>
        <li ng-class="{active:tab('public4')}"><a href="/public4">public4</a></li>
        <li ng-class="{active:tab('register')}"><a href="/register">register</a></li>
        <li ng-show="authenticated2()"><a href="" ng-click="logout()">logout</a></li>
    </ul>
```

The `tab()` method in the `navigation.js` controller is:

```
$scope.tab = function(route) {
    return $route.current && route === $route.current.controller;
};
```

Comment: please post your JS for the function `tab()`

Comment: @mani I just added `tab` to the OP.  What else can I provide to make the solution more apparent?